# TCP/HTTP proxy in node.js

Tags: http, node.js, proxy, tcp

I'd like to create a simple TCP and HTTP proxy in node.js - For example, the proxy listens on port 8080 and redirects all TCP requests to `127.0.0.1:8181` and all HTTP requests to `127.0.0.0.1:8282`

I found this snippet on Google for a simple HTTP proxy in 20 lines of code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var proxy = http.createClient(80, request.headers['host'])
  var proxy_request = proxy.request(request.method, request.url, request.headers);
  proxy_request.addListener('response', function (proxy_response) {
    proxy_response.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
      response.write(chunk, 'binary');
    });
    proxy_response.addListener('end', function() {
      response.end();
    });
    response.writeHead(proxy_response.statusCode, proxy_response.headers);
  });
  request.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    proxy_request.write(chunk, 'binary');
  });
  request.addListener('end', function() {
    proxy_request.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

So basically I need to listen for any sort of request on 8080, guess if it's TCP or HTTP, and then proxy the request to the right path. Any tips using the snippet above?

Thanks

Comment: HTTP is application level transport over TCP. I'm guessing you are saying 'try to check if this tcp data makes valid http request'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nodejitsu](http://www.nodejitsu.com/#/home) has open-sourced a [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which I think you try  instead. It is  documented, actively developed.